# What would be the consequences of proving Riemann's hypothesis for Legendre's conjecture?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-hypothesis

I've heard somewhere that Riemann's hypothesis doesn't imply Legendre's conjecture. But if Riemann's hypothesis is true, would an interval maybe a bit larger than $[n^2,(n+1)^2]$ contain always at least one prime?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In particular, Cramér proved that under RH, prime gaps are $O(\sqrt x\log x)$ and this can be made effective with a result of Schoenfeld. So you're 'only' off by a factor of roughly $\frac{\log x}{4\pi}$ once you have RH.

1. Harold Cramér, Some theorems concerning prime numbers, *Arkiv för Matematik, Astronomi och Fysik* **15**, #5 (1920), pp. 1–32.
2. Lowell Schoenfeld, Sharper bounds for the Chebyshev functions θ(x) and ψ(x). II, *Mathematics of Computation* **30**:134 (1976), pp. 337–360.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The reason why I ask the question is that I've been told that the asymptotic formula $\pi(x+y)-\pi(x)\sim y/\ln x$ holds for $y\ge x^{1/2+\epsilon}$ if Riemann's hypothesis is true, but I would like to have a journal references for this. Do you know of any source where I can find this conditional result?

Comment: @user135328: Well, that's a different question entirely! I think that was proved as well, but later than Cramér's result. I don't have a reference handy, but if you want to post this question separately someone might know it. Otherwise I'll see if I can dig it up in my notes.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'll post the question separately.

Comment: @user135328: I'll start looking for the reference.

Comment: I've posted the question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/718666/a-question-about-an-asymptotic-formula.