# A question about an asymptotic formula

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, riemann-hypothesis, prime-gaps

I've been told that the asymptotic formula $\pi(x+y)-\pi(x)\sim y/\ln x$ holds for $y\ge x^{1/2+\varepsilon}$ if Riemann's hypothesis is true, but I was unable to find a journal reference for this. Does anybody know of any journal reference or any other source where I can find this conditional result?

Comment: I added the reference-request tag, since this is what your question is.  I had to remove the asymptotics tag, though.

Comment: no problem, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the original source, but you can find the result in

- Helmut Maier, [Primes in short intervals](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.mmj/1029003189), *Michigan Math. J.* **32**:2 (1985), pp. 131–255.

There are more details in

- D. R. Heath-Brown, The number of primes in a short interval, *Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik* (Crelles Journal), **389** (1988), pp. 22–63.

which proves a weaker result without RH.

Selberg had earlier proved that this, and more, is true (unconditionally) for a set of density 1:

- A. Selberg, An elementary proof of the Prime Number Theorem, *Ann. of Math.* **50** (1949), pp. 305–313.

Comment: thank you!! the first reference you've provided is enough for me

Comment: @user135328: Glad to help, sorry I couldn't find the original source.